# Regular expression to check 3 uppercase letters anywhere

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that checks whether a string has 3 uppercase lettrs. Those letters need not to be one after the other.

I know how to check whether a string has any uppercase letter by using (?=.*?[A-Z]) but i could not go beyond this

```
WsswFeA - will match
AAtrW   - will match
srABFes - will match
srtZfgQ - will not match
```

pleas help me

Comment: How will `WsswfeA` match since there are only 2 capital letters.

Comment: sorry its a typo. I have updated it.

Comment: ok great then my answer should for you in all the cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to use lookahead for this.
Using the same idea as anubhava went with, but putting it in the body of the regexp instead should also work.

```
^(.*[A-Z]){3}.*$
```

As you noted in your question `.*[A-Z]` checks for a single uppercase letter.  So to look for 3 of them we just repeat that 3 times.  `(foo){3}` is a regexp shorthand for `(foo)(foo)(foo)`.

In your regexp you started the group with `?=`, meaning that this was a lookahead.  This essentially asks the matcher if there is a match on the assertion starting on the subgroup you are currently on.  However, since this is the only condition we are testing for we might as well make it our primary expression and avoid the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=(.*?[A-Z]){3}).{3,}$
```

This `positive lookahead` `(?=(.*?[A-Z]){3})` will make sure sure that there are at least 3 capital letters anywhere in the input text.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
^(.*[A-Z]){3,}.*$
```

<kbd>[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?37k70)</kbd>